# Remove calling method on the template when there is loop

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I know calling method on the template is not good since it fires each and every time on change detection. But how can I remove that on below code? The problem here is it should work under the loop. Otherwise, I can do that. Any clue here?

```
  <ion-slides>
    <ion-slide *ngFor='let page of pages'>
      <img [src]='imageHandlingProvider.normalizeImageFileUri(page.documentPreviewImageFileUri)' />
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

*provider.ts*

```
 normalizeImageFileUri(imageFileUri: string): string {
    console.log('imageFileUri', imageFileUri);
    return normalizeURL(imageFileUri);
  }
```

Comment: looks like you need the `page` object just to get the source, create a pipe which does this for you and use the return of pipe intead

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear for me. can you construct a Pseudocode here? @xyz

Comment: In ts file after you get the `pages` loop through it and add a new attribute line "normalizedURL" with the value `normalizeImageFileUri(page.documentPreviewImageFileUri)`. now we need to process the `pages` array one.

Comment: Can you construct an answer? It is not clear to me. @RANJITPATRA

Comment: Okay let add a pseducode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a pipe which processes your `pages` array and returns only the "normalized" url which you want in as `[src]`

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
      name: 'normalizeUri'
    })
    export class NormalizeUriPipe implements PipeTransform {

      constructor(private _imageHandlingProvider: ImageHandlingProvider) {}

      transform(pages: any): string[] {
        return pages.map((eachPage) => {
          return this._imageHandlingProvider.normalizeURL(eachPage.documentPreviewImageFileUri);
        })

      }

    }
```

Use this pipe in your template as:

```
<ion-slide *ngFor='let uri of pages | normalizeUri'>
  <img [src]="uri" />
</ion-slide>
```

Comment: This works like a charm and perfect solution too. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Sampath: Oh! my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Here we are trying to add the `normalizedURL` a new attribute to each `"page" object. So in the html we need to bind the new arrtubute`normalizedURL`.

In the process `processPages()` need to be called after each loading of `"pages"`.

```
processPages() {
    this.pages.forEach((page) => {
        page.normalizedURL = imageHandlingProvider.normalizeImageFileUri(page.documentPreviewImageFileUri)
    })
}
```

And corresponding html code.

```
<ion-slides>
    <ion-slide *ngFor='let page of pages'>
        <img [src]='page?.normalizedURL' />
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```